# SharePoint Workflows - Custom Approval - Can I get it to email the field that was updated?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

Working with a SP list, have a standard approval workflow that kicks off when an item on the list is updated. I have it set to send the alerting email and have my custom message

Is there any way to have the email contain the fields that were updated (as in field x was value A and was updated to value B)?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with standard workflow (or even with workflows at all). More suitable would be using `SPEventReceiver.ItemUpdating` to check what fields have their values changed, and send summary email from there.

Or, you can always turn on versioning (only major) and create custom activity used in workflow, that could extract required information from previous version of item (i'm not aware of any such OOTB functionality availble)